# Angular 5 : select all users with related role OneToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate, typescript, spring-boot, angular5

I'm trying to select all users with related role, knowing that one role can be related to many contacts and one contact has one role.

i tried the code bellow but it return just a blank table, is it a problem with hibernate or with how i called the company name column ?

**ContactRepository.java**

```
@Query("SELECT c, cmp.name FROM Contact c, Company cmp WHERE c.company=cmp.id")
public Page<Contact> search(Pageable page);
```

**ContactRestService**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/searchContacts", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<Contact> search(
            @RequestParam(name="page",defaultValue="0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name="size",defaultValue="5") int size){
        return contactRepository.search(PageRequest.of(page, size));    
    }
```

**contacts.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of pageContacts?.content">
    <td class="py-1">
        <img src="../../assets/images/faces-clipart/pic-1.png" alt="image"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{c.email}}</td>
    <td>{{c.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{c.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{c.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{c.job}}</td>
    <td>{{c.birthday}}</td>
    <td>{{c.company.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**contact.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactsService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

  getContacts(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/searchContacts?page=0&size=6")
  }

}
```

**contacts.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

  pageContacts:any;
  constructor(private contactsService:ContactsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Initialisation......");
    this.contactsService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.pageContacts=data;
      }, err=>{
      console.log("ALERT!!!!!"+err);
      })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the response is an array so it works when i changed my code to this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of pageContacts?.content">
    <td class="py-1">
        <img src="../../assets/images/faces-clipart/pic-1.png" alt="image"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{c[0].email}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].phone}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].job}}</td>
    <td>{{c[0].birthday}}</td>
    <td>{{c[1]}}</td>
</tr>
```